# Amazon Athena returning `HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR` on geo json

Tags: hive, amazon-athena

I'm trying to read a geojson file using Amazon Athena.

The head of my input data looks like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "sql_statement",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gridsize": 500.0, "big_gid": 353, "little_gid": 22482 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -981739.267883020918816, 30855.609566356935829 ], [ -981739.267883020918816, 31355.354737498135364 ], [ -981241.022986860014498, 31355.354737498135364 ], [ -981241.022986860014498, 30855.609566356935829 ], [ -981739.267883020918816, 30855.609566356935829 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gridsize": 500.0, "big_gid": 353, "little_gid": 22483 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -981241.022986860014498, 30855.609566356935829 ], [ -981241.022986860014498, 31355.354737498135364 ], [ -980742.778090699226595, 31355.354737498135364 ], [ -980742.778090699226595, 30855.609566356935829 ], [ -981241.022986860014498, 30855.609566356935829 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gridsize": 500.0, "big_gid": 353, "little_gid": 22484 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -980742.778090699226595, 30855.609566356935829 ], [ -980742.778090699226595, 31355.354737498135364 ], [ -980244.533194538322277, 31355.354737498135364 ], [ -980244.533194538322277, 30855.609566356935829 ], [ -980742.778090699226595, 30855.609566356935829 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gridsize": 500.0, "big_gid": 353, "little_gid": 22485 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -980244.533194538322277, 30855.609566356935829 ], [ -980244.533194538322277, 31355.354737498135364 ], [ -979746.288298377417959, 31355.354737498135364 ], [ -979746.288298377417959, 30855.609566356935829 ], [ -980244.533194538322277, 30855.609566356935829 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gridsize": 500.0, "big_gid": 353, "little_gid": 22486 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -979746.288298377417959, 30855.609566356935829 ], [ -979746.288298377417959, 31355.354737498135364 ], [ -979248.043402216513641, 31355.354737498135364 ], [ -979248.043402216513641, 30855.609566356935829 ], [ -979746.288298377417959, 30855.609566356935829 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gridsize": 500.0, "big_gid": 353, "little_gid": 22487 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -979248.043402216513641, 30855.609566356935829 ], [ -979248.043402216513641, 31355.354737498135364 ], [ -978749.798506055609323, 31355.354737498135364 ], [ -978749.798506055609323, 30855.609566356935829 ], [ -979248.043402216513641, 30855.609566356935829 ] ] ] } },
```

and I defined the table using the [geospatial documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/geospatial-example-queries.html) as a template:

```
CREATE external TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testdb.grid_500
 (
 gridsize double,
 big_gid int, 
 little_gid int, 
 geometry binary
 )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.JsonSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.esri.json.hadoop.EnclosedJsonInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://jdl-athena/grid/'
;
```

Any query I run against the table, however, returns the same, rather unhelpful, error:

> ```
> Your query has the following error(s):
>
> HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR
>
> This query ran against the "testdb" database, unless qualified by the query.
> Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with 
> Query Id: 25d3da93-5cfd-46bb-9f77-4eb014679ba6.
> ```

Any ideas why I might be receiving this error or how I might go about debugging it? I can't even figure out how to get enough info to diagnose what might be happening.

Answer (score 2):

So after much Google Fu, I have discovered that (of course) ESRI has created their own JSON format for geographic data. I am using the open standard `GeoJson` and the ESRI format is called [`ESRI Enclosed JSON`](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/wiki/JSON-Formats). For geometric JSON, Athena supports only the ESRI format, not GEOJSON.

I discovered this distinction here: 
https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/issues/29

So it looks like I need my input data in a different format.

Comment: This just saved me some time.  Thanks!